# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android

i am struggling a little bit over here, i have a research button in my application, that will call a PHP file to do a SELECT ( and get several lines). Here is my php file:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("***", "***", "***", "***");  
$city = $_POST["city"];  
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT name FROM Restaurants WHERE city = ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $city);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $city);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  
$i=-1

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement)){
        $i++;

        $response["name"][$i]=$row[$i];
        $response["name"][$i]=$row[$i];

    }       
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I am getting an error from .java file. Here is the button listener in my .java file:

```
public void bSearchRestaurantClicked(View v) {

    final EditText etCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchRestaurantsCity);
    final String city = etCity.getText().toString();

    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                if (success) {

                    String nameCities = jsonResponse.getString("name");

                    System.out.println("=======> "+nameCities);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(AreaActivityClient.this, ResultSearchActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("city", city);

                    intent.putExtra("cities", nameCities);

                    AreaActivityClient.this.startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AreaActivityClient.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Login Failed !").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(city, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AreaActivityClient.this);
    queue.add(searchRequest);
```

The error is in this line:

```
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

And here is my SearchRequest.java file:

```
private static final String SEARCH_REQUEST_URL="file.php";
private Map<String,String> params;
public SearchRequest(String city, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Request.Method.POST,SEARCH_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("city",city);
}
```

I am pretty sure that the error is from the .php file, but i can't find it...
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can

```
log.v(response);
```

then check response is a JSON String

debug from simple to complex